# Why "Find my phone" is sending a SMS and doesn't work?

Tags: find-my-phone

Actually is a friend phone. A new Lumia 710 but I had this same problem when I bought my Samsung Focus. After some days my Focus starts to work with "Find my phone".

What happen is that the phone only receive a SMS message with something that looks like this:

> SkY#AAh1D9AxApg2O+oypHX0wpbFRjKQQDBVuvPcggnw28VCXSl1FMXC3hk5H/Kfgrv/il21Qi==

The phone has the option "*Connect to these features faster*" and "*Save my locations every few hours for better mapping*" enable.

The phone has internet connection.

The phone has not battery save enable this momment.

Another [question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-setting-up-do-i-need-to-do-for-find-my-phone-to-work) is related but did not mention the SMS.

Comment: @DownVoter Can you explain why you downvote?

Answer (score 3):

The way the Microsoft server sends commands to the phone is through SMS. Things like downloading an app from the web marketplace or using the Find My Phone feature sends a remote command that is not supposed to be seen by the user. It is not even supposed to even activate the messaging app. (There was even a command discovered last year that would screw your phone up royally, but they patched that up quick)

So what you are seeing is that command, this is a serious issue. I would contact @winphonesupport on twitter and let them know this happened. By knowing any of these commands, you could remotely control another users phone.

Comment: So "find my phone" sent that message but it cannot understand. Why?

Comment: It is strange that the phone isn't executing the command. I'm apt to believe there is something wrong with the command, it may not be formatted right. I thought they all started with the # sign. The flow is thought to be like this. User clicks "find my phone", server sends text command, phone responds via cell tower with triangulation or last known GPS, then refines with current gps

Comment: I think it is not always the case. Sometimes it uses push instead of SMS.